# I can't create context with typescript react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

if I use .js instead of .tsx there is no problem. but when I use typescript, it shows this error "Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.". what am I missing ?

context.tsx

```js
import { createContext, useContext} from "react";

const MainContext = createContext();

export {
    MainContext,
    useContext
}
```

Layout.tsx

```
const LayoutComponent = ({children}: any) => {

   const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

 const data = {
   email,
   setEmail
 }

  return (
     <MainContext.Provider value={data}>
      <Header />
      {children}
     </MainContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use default value

```
import { createContext, useContext} from "react";

const ctx = createContext({ someData: true })

export const useCtx = () => useContext(ctx)
```

Answer (score 0):

[createContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext) needs a default value

```
const MainContext = createContext({});
```